# Xfce4 WaveLAN plugin doesn't work - permission problem?

Tags: xfce, wifi, netcfg

I've just made fresh install of Arch Linux on my EEEPC, and I have problem with Wi-Fi panel icon in Xfce. After clicking it, nothing happens, and what should happen is a window opening where i can select network to connect to. Also, the tooltip says "No such WaveLAN device". When I right-click it and open properties, the "Interface" box says "wlp1s0", which is the name of my wlan interface. When I connect to network via netcfg or wifi-menu (which requires root priviledges, and aren't automatic) everything works good, even the WaveLAN's signal indicator shows signal correctly - but I still can't access network selection window.

What's the potential cause of this behavior, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out... The WaveLAN plugin isn't for connecting - it's for status checking *only*. I was confused, because on my previous installation, I had a tray icon, but forgot it's from Wicd GUI. I replaced netcfg with wicd, installed wicd-gtk, and I've got another icon in tray automatically, so I don't need WaveLAN at all now. Mea culpa x)